# How can i subtract from today's date -30 days from my database that uses ( date )

Tags: php, database

I need help on figuring out how to -30 days from a database table  by date 
and then count how many invoices there are that are  -30 days old  from todays date

Answer (score 17):

To reduce 30 days from today in php

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
```

Comment: thanks, i will test out .... is there anyway instead of showing the date that it will count how many  there are by -30 days?

Comment: sorry I can't get you... what you want to count?

Comment: what i am asking instead of showing the ( date ) that i would be able to ( count ) the ( dates ) that are all -30 days  and then the echo would only show the  number of all ( -30 days ) rows in my table

Comment: In your above query add the date in where condition eg: where `duedate` = 'date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'))'

Comment: I will insert code and test out .. thanks

Comment: Having issues it still outputing the full y-m-d date instead of just counting all invoices that are -30 days old  as a number.

Comment: update your query in the question and on which table you have the date column

Comment: i will update query and... the ( date ) table is on ( invoices )  labeled ( duedate)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL use `interval`, e.g.:

```sql
create temporary table tmp (
  d timestamp not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);

insert into tmp values
(now() - interval 1 day),
(now() - interval 32 day),
(now() - interval 33 day),
(now() - interval 10 day);

select * from tmp where d between now() - interval 30 day and now();
```

Comment: In general non deterministic functions like `now()` should be avoided in queries. It doesn't impact `INSERT` or `UDPATE` queries but it disables query cache on `SELECT`. For this reason it's a nice habit to prepare date strings/timestamps before passing to DBMS...